# Ethernet Shield Stops After a While

Tags: arduino, ethernet, rfid

I use Ethernet shield (W5100) and RC522 on my Arduino Uno. It works 1 or 2 hours (sometimes 15 minutes - sometimes 2 days) After this random time, it stops working. I mean stop with, RC-522 module don't read cards, and ethernet shield can't connect server. When i unplug power (1.5A - 12 V power suply) and re-plug it, it starts working successfully.

I need to this system works forever... This system reads mifare card, and sends to the server, after that it checks reply, and if the reply is "1", it triggers relay. (relay is 5V simple relay)

Some people said "Change your adaptor", and i changed it, nothing changed.
Some people said " use 10 microfarad capasitor between rst and gnd pin" and nothing changed. 
and some people said, "this is arduino dude, it is for just studend give up and use stm32", and i didn't apply this suggestion yet. I want to know why this happens.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

//Mac address of ethernet shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xEA }; 

//My Network info, i use static ip
byte ip[] = { 172, 16, 64, 78 }; 
byte gateway[] = { 172, 16, 64, 1 }; 
byte myserver[] = { 172, 16, 64, 46 }; 
byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 }; 

String CardInfo = "";
EthernetClient client;
String GateNo = "0";
String DeviceNo = "100";

String Answer = "";


MFRC522 mfrc522;
byte Key[] = { 0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff };
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;


void setup(){
  //Disabling SD Card
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, subnet, gateway);

  KeyCreate();

  mfrc522.PCD_Init(2, 8); 
  mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();

}



void sendGET()
{
  //I used this line to guarantee the disconnect from server
  client.stop();
  Answer = "";
  if (client.connect(myserver, 81)) {  
    client.println("GET /AccessCheck/CardNo=" + CardInfo + "&GateNo=" + GateNo + "&DeviceNo=" + DeviceNo + " HTTP/1.0");
    client.println("Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    client.println(); 
  } 
  else {
    //Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, subnet, gateway);
    return;
  }

  int connectLoop = 0;
  while(client.connected())
  {
    while(client.available())
    {
      char c = client.read();
      Answer = Answer + c;
      connectLoop = 0;
    }

    delay(1);
    connectLoop++;
    if(connectLoop > 5000)
    {
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }
  client.stop();
}

//This function disables eth and enable rc522 (and reverse)
void Switch(int i)
{
  switch (i)
  {
    case 0:
      digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
      break;
    case 1:
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10, LOW);
      break;
  }
}

void AccessControl()
{
  int AnswerLength = Answer.length();

  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);

  if(Answer[AnswerLength-1] == 49)
  {
    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  }
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
  delay(1000);
}

void ReadCard()
{
  byte len = 18;
  MFRC522::StatusCode status;

  byte MyBuffer[18];
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 10, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(10, MyBuffer, &len);
  int counter = 0;
  //This line is check for turkish character
  if(MyBuffer[0] == 221)
  {
    CardInfo = "X";
    for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
    {
      if (MyBuffer[i] != 32)
      {
        CardInfo = CardInfo + (char)MyBuffer[i];
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    CardInfo = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
      if (MyBuffer[i] != 32)
      {
        CardInfo = CardInfo + (char)MyBuffer[i];
      }
    }
  }

  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();
  return;
}

void KeyCreate()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    key.keyByte[i] = Key[i];
  }
}

void loop(){
  Switch(0);
  if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        ReadCard(); 
        Switch(1);
        sendGET();
        AccessControl();
  }
}
```

I expect it runs without freezing

Actual result is ethernet shield freezes after a while

Comment: instead unplug and replug the power, if you push the reset button is it ok to restart all the system ? the program is frozen or it is functional and it gives errors ?

Comment: no reset doesnt work, i have to replug power otherwise it dont work.

Comment: have you try watchdog?

Answer (score 0):

I am using watchdog in some script . This functionality could reset auomatically your arduino if you dont reset the watchdog during the lapse.

you execute wdt_enable() in the setup()  and wd_reset() at the beginning of the loop

```
time before watchdog firing    argument of wdt_enable()
-------------------------------------------------------
15mS                           WDTO_15MS
30mS                           WDTO_30MS
60mS                           WDTO_60MS
120mS                          WDTO_120MS
250mS                          WDTO_250MS
500mS                          WDTO_500MS
1S                             WDTO_1S            
2S                             WDTO_2S
4S                             WDTO_4S
8S                             WDTO_8S
```

example of use:

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>

void setup()
{
  wdt_enable(WDTO_4S);       // enable the watchdog
                             // will fire after 4s without reset
}

void loop(){
 wdt_reset();              // resets the watchdog timer count
     :
     :
                     // if program hangs more than 4s, launch the reset of arduino
}
```

Comment: and about the result of test?